# .Net framework prerequisite (4.5.2) in Visual Studio 2013 setup project doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation, setup-deployment, prerequisites, .net-4.5.2

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and the setup extension to create my installer. I am setting .Net 4.5.2 as prerequisite but this doesn't prompt the user to install .Net framework 4.5.2 at installation. Anyone else faced similar issue or can suggest any solution.

Comment: There were very good reasons why it was removed from Visual Studio, you discovered one.  Otherwise an excellent hint to retarget your project to 4.5, the odds that you actually *need* 4.5.2 are as low as your customer's willingness to install it.  It sings a very strange swan-song on programmers, everybody completely ignored 4.01, 4.02 and 4.03 but the equivalent 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 updates have much higher visibility for some reason.

Comment: Thanks. I agree and thought the same. We are planning to move to InstallShield for these reasons.

Answer (score 2):

The prerequisite of .Net Framework 4.5.2 doesn't work in the setup project extension of VS2013, but I found a workaround to make it working.

To make it work you can edit the .vdproj manually.
You need to edit the below mentioned tag in .vdproj file from:

```
"LaunchCondition"
            {
                "{A06ECF26-33A3-4562-8140-9B0E340D4F24}:_BD8A05B1D41349D39EF455D73B3E0C43"
                {
                "Name" = "8:.NET Framework"
                "Message" = "8:[VSDNETMSG]"
                "FrameworkVersion" = "8:.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"
                "AllowLaterVersions" = "11:FALSE"
                "InstallUrl" = "8:http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=131000"
                }
            }
```

to:

```
"LaunchCondition"
            {
                "{A06ECF26-33A3-4562-8140-9B0E340D4F24}:_BD8A05B1D41349D39EF455D73B3E0C43"
                {
                "Name" = "8:.NET Framework"
                "Message" = "8:[VSDNETMSG]"
                "FrameworkVersion" = "8:.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"
                "AllowLaterVersions" = "11:FALSE"
                "InstallUrl" = "8:https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42642"
                }
            }
```

Basically you need to change the .net framework version and link to download the .net framework 4.5.2

Comment: You also need to document that such an edit will disappear without a trace when you make *any* minor change to the setup project.